# Compilation problem on armhf with cmake on qt "Syntax error: wird unexpected (expecting ")""

Tags: c++, qt, arm, cross-compiling

recently i've been interested in qt for my work, I started a project on it and i needed to cross compile it.
On my computer, everything seems to work just fine like you can see below but on my colleague's computer I've got some errors. I've been searching for some answers but didn't find anything ...

```
~/work/qt/malo_zelie/armhf_build >cmake ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: malo_zelie/armhf_build
    ~/work/qt/malo_zelie/armhf_build >make
Scanning dependencies of target malo_zelie_automoc
[ 16%] Automatic moc, uic and rcc for target malo_zelie
Generating moc source malo_zelie_automoc.dir/moc_mainwindow_BMDIVWC5MAP5U5.cpp
Generating moc compilation malo_zelie_automoc.cpp
Generating ui header ui_mainwindow.h
[ 16%] Built target malo_zelie_automoc
[ 33%] Generating ../malo_zelie_fr_FR.ts
Scanning directory '/home/mael/work/qt/malo_zelie'...
Updating '../malo_zelie_fr_FR.ts'...
    Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
Scanning dependencies of target malo_zelie
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/malo_zelie.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/malo_zelie.dir/src/mainwindow.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/malo_zelie.dir/malo_zelie_automoc.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable malo_zelie
[100%] Built target malo_zelie
```

but on my friend's computer here is what I got :

```
    :~/workspace/malo_zelie_qt/armhf_build$ cmake ..
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: malo_zelie_qt/armhf_build
    colin@debian:~/workspace/malo_zelie_qt/armhf_build$ make
    [ 16%] Automatic moc, uic and rcc for target malo_zelie
    Generating moc source malo_zelie_automoc.dir/moc_mainwindow_BMDIVWC5MAP5U5.cpp
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/moc: 1: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/moc: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
    AUTOGEN: error: process for /home/colin/workspace/malo_zelie_qt/armhf_build/malo_zelie_automoc.dir/moc_mainwindow_BMDIVWC5MAP5U5.cpp failed:
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/moc: 1: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/moc: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
    Generating moc compilation malo_zelie_automoc.cpp
    Generating ui header ui_mainwindow.h
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/uic: 1: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/uic: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
    AUTOUIC: error: process for ui_mainwindow.h needed by
     "/home/colin/workspace/malo_zelie_qt/src/mainwindow.cpp"
    failed:
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/uic: 1: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/uic: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
    moc failed...
    CMakeFiles/malo_zelie_automoc.dir/build.make:57 : la recette pour la cible « CMakeFiles/malo_zelie_automoc » a échouée
    make[2]: [CMakeFiles/malo_zelie_automoc] 
Erreur 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104 : la recette pour la cible « CMakeFiles/malo_zelie_automoc.dir/all » a échouée make[1]: [CMakeFiles/malo_zelie_automoc.dir/all] 
Erreur 2 Makefile:83 : la recette pour la cible « all » a échouée make: [all] Erreur 2
```

here is the CmakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(malo_zelie LANGUAGES CXX)

set( CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/Qt/5.15.0" )

option( USE_CLANG "Use Clang compiler." OFF )
option( USE_LIBCPP "Use LLVM's libc++ instead of GNU's libstdc++ (requires clang)" OFF )
option( USE_ARMHF "use armhf compiler and linker." OFF)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package(Qt5 ...) call.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

if( USE_ARMHF )
        set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/")
        set( COMXENTEO "ComXenteo2-armhf")
        set( CMAKE_LINKER "arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld")
        set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" )
        set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FMAGS} -Wno-attributes")
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g3" )
        set( Qt5Core_DIR "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Core" )
        set( Qt5Gui_DIR "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Gui" )
        set( Qt5LinguistTools_DIR "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5LinguistTools" )
        set( Qt5Widgets_DIR "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Widgets" )
        set( Qt5_DIR "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5" )
else()
        set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
        set( Qt5Core_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core" )
        set( Qt5Gui_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui" )
        set( Qt5LinguistTools_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5LinguistTools" )
        set( Qt5Widgets_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Widgets" )
        set( Qt5_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5" )
        set(COMXENTEO "ComXenteo2-x64")
        if( USE_CLANG )
                set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++" )
                set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Weverything" )
                set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-padded" )
                set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-weak-vtables" )
                set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic" )
                set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-exit-time-destructors" )
                set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-global-constructors" )
                if( USE_LIBCPP )
                        set( ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++" )
                endif        
      endif()
endif()

find_package( Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets LinguistTools REQUIRED)

set(TS_FILES malo_zelie_fr_FR.ts)

file( GLOB malo_zelie_src "src/*.cpp" "src/*.h" "src/*.ui" )

if(ANDROID)
  add_library(malo_zelie SHARED
                ${malo_zelie_src}
    ${TS_FILES}
  )
else()
  add_executable(malo_zelie
                ${malo_zelie_src}
    ${TS_FILES}
  )
endif()

set( EXT_LIBS
        #       ${sga_LIBRARIES}
        ${COMXENTEO}
)

set( EXT_INCLUDES
        #       ${sga_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set( EXT_COMP
        # ${sga_CFLAGS_OTHER}
)

target_link_libraries( malo_zelie PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets ${EXT_LIBS} )
target_include_directories( malo_zelie PUBLIC src ${EXT_INCLUDES} )
target_compile_options( malo_zelie PUBLIC ${EXT_COMP} )

qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})()
```

does someone has any idea ? Sorry for the clumsy post, it's my first one.

Comment: Those errors are typical of attempts to execute a binary compiled for a given platform on an incompatible one. I would say your build process is attempting to execute armhf versions of moc, uic and rcc on an x86_64 PC. If you are cross-compiling, the x86_64 versions are the one that should be used. I am not a Qt user, but you can probably specify what are the exact moc, uic and rcc that should be called duting the build process. The Qt  documentation should indicate how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Okey that was it, thanx to Frant, on my computer there was qemu installed so I could run arm binary, but on my colleague's computer, qemu wasn't installed and moc uic and rcc called are arm binary, I should change this in the future but for now I just installed qemu on his computer and everythings works just fine, thx.